# Is it possible, through Screen time API to get the iPhone usage time raw data for each app programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible, through Screen time API to get the iPhone usage time raw data for each app programmatically? I want to create an app which tells me how much time I spend on each app on my iPhone.
Screen time API.
Device activity.

Comment: No, it is not.  Apps cannot access specific app usage details via the Screen time API.  It is privacy protected information.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide a public API specifically for accessing raw data related to screen time or app usage on iOS devices. The Screen Time feature on iOS devices is primarily designed for individual users to monitor and manage their own device usage.

Apple does provide limited access to some Screen Time data through the Screen Time widget and notifications, but this data is not available through a public API for third-party developers to use programmatically.